# Which model association for messages and many users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im new to Rails and actually im trying to write my own messaging application. So far i have many users with username, password, etc. And now im figuering out how i should best write the migration for the message model. I thought that a message needs:

**Message**

```
 sender_id => integer
 recipent_id => integer
 created_at => time
 updated_at => time
```

The **first problem** im facing is that of course sender_id is unique but what is with recipent_id, there are often messages that should go to several people!

**Next problem** is i dont know how i have to refer form the user model to the message model i mean normaly i would write:

**User** has_many :messages

**Message** belongs_to :user

To do this i would need a coulmn named user_id in the message model , but now i have two cloumns sender_id and reciepent_id!

I hope you can give my some hints! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "sender_id" #this only gives the messages sent by the user.
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  #sender_id
  belongs_to :sender, :class => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :recipients, :class => "MessageRecipient"
end

class MessageRecipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, :class => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
end
```

If you want to get all the recipients for the message, you could do

```
message.recipients.collect(&:email)
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it and when i have further questions i will come back to you! But for now thanks

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606459/how-to-get-not-only-single-record-but-all-records-that-belong-to-specific-search